# Unable to save to database data from a vue-cool-select input element

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have this input with a vue-cool-select where the user can start writing and it shows cities from the cool select.
The v-model should save the city to the database, but I'm receiving an error message *CANNOT POST CITIES* and the browser console started showing several errors that I have no idea how to solve them...
One of the errors I need to solve is it down here:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "cities" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

The code is it:

```html
<template>
    ...
    <b-form-group label="Nome:" label-for="city-name">
                    <b-form-input id="city-name" type="text"
                        v-model="city.name" required
                        :readonly="mode === 'remove'"
                        placeholder="Informe o Nome da Cidade..." />
                </b-form-group>
                <b-form-group label="Cidade de Origem:" label-for="city-parentId">
                    <cool-select v-if="mode === 'save'" :options="selected" v-model="city.parentId" :items='items'
                        :error-message="errorMessage" />
                        <span slot="error" slot-scope="{ errorMessage }">
                            Error: {{ errorMessage }}
                        </span>
                </b-form-group>
    </template>
```

```js
    import { baseApiUrl, showError } from '@/global'
    import { CoolSelect } from 'vue-cool-select'
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    export default {
        name: 'CityAdmin',
        data: function() {
            return {
                mode: 'save',
                city: {},
                cities: [],
                fields: [
                    { key: 'id', label: 'Código', sortable: true },
                    { key: 'name', label: 'Nome', sortable: true },
                    { key: 'path', label: 'Caminho', sortable: true },
                    { key: 'actions', label: 'Ações' }
                ],
                selected: null,
                items: [ ... MORE THAN 5000 CITIES IN HERE ... ],
                    errorMessage: null
            }
        },
        watch: {
            selected() {
                this.validate();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loadCities() {
                const url = `${baseApiUrl}/cities`
                axios.get(url).then(res => {
                    // this.cities = res.data
                    this.cities = res.data.map(city => {
                        return { ...city, value: city.id, text: city.path }
                    })
                })
            },
            reset() { 
                this.mode = 'save'
                this.city = {}
                this.loadCities()
            },
            save() {
                const method = this.city.id ? 'put' : 'post'
                const id = this.city.id ? `/${this.city.id}` : ''
                axios[method](`${baseApiUrl}/cities${id}`, this.city)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.$toasted.global.defaultSuccess()
                        this.reset()
                    })
                    .catch(showError)
            },
            remove() {
                const id = this.city.id
                axios.delete(`${baseApiUrl}/cities/${id}`)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.$toasted.global.defaultSuccess()
                        this.reset()
                    })
                    .catch(showError)
            },
            loadCity(city, mode = 'save') {
                this.mode = mode
                this.city = { ...city }
            },
            validate() {
                this.errorMessage = !this.selected ? 'Este é um campo obrigatório!': null;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadCities()
        },
        components: {
            CoolSelect
        }
    }
```

I hope I can get some help